# Fail to run chromedriver on win computer

Tags: scala, selenium, selenium-webdriver, package, selenium-chromedriver

I have a program that doing some kind of automation and im compressing it to a packagebin using `sbt universal:packageBin` and then im sending it to some people that run the but file and then they can run the program locally on their machine.

When im using `firefoxdriver` there is no problem, the problem occurs when the driver is `chromedriver`...I get an error that I need to download the `chromedriver` to their machine...so I read about it and I need to download the exe file of `chromedriver` and give it a env variable for the path...did it but still not working.

Do you know what do I need to do?

(im using scala and selenium as far as technologies, although its not making a diff)

Comment: you need to locate the chromedriver in your path.

Comment: Hi, in your local file it may not cause any problem because you have the exe file for it where else the other end person have the batch file they need the chrome exe file. You can just send the exe file also with it.

Comment: What do you mean by `still not working`?? could you share your code which have you tried as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hi I have got the following approach try it:

System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","chrome driver downloaded path");
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();